# Detox - Record a single video from beginning to the end

Tags: react-native, detox

Our team is using RN Detox which helps a lot our testing team.

I'm not sure this is currently possible, but in our workflow we would like to have a second check by someone watching the video recorded during the tests (to check the design / the values etc).
Recording the videos is perfectly working on iOS with --record-videos all but it generates one video for each item of each test.

Is there a way to generate only one video for the whole series of tests ?

Comment: I just found a way to handle this using bash scripts and `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo`

Comment: Note you can write answers to your own question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to handle this using bash scripts and xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo

Comment: Could you share how this works with the people you asked for help in the first place please?

Comment: Sure, `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo --codec h264 scripts/appvideo.mov` starts recording a video of the simulator. Then I start `detox test`. But the tricky part was to stop recording once the test is done : 
`process=$(ps aux | grep recordVideo | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')` to find the pid of the process, and `kill -SIGINT $process` to kill it. 
With a few more lines, the video is reduced with ffmpeg, and sent to Slack ;)

Comment: This is a workaround of course, it is just used for our testing team